# How to set Focus for the Pop-up error message?

Tags: asp.net, html, setfocus

I need to set the focus for the POP-UP window so that the Screen reader reads out the error message twice.

```
if (Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text.Trim()).DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
{
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "PopUp", "alert('Previous week start date should be a Monday !');", true);
  return;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to select the text part in alert popup?

Comment: yes @ Sunil... I want the screen reader to read out the text for second time

Comment: You could reload the same page using a JavaScript timer, which would display the same alert again and it would be read by the screen reader a second time. If you are ok with this, then I can provide the code to do this.

Comment: I am ok with this @Sunil... please provide the code

Comment: Before I do that, I wanted to make sure whether the screen reader is reading the alert text once when alert is shown?

Comment: yes.. the screen reader reads out the message for the first time when it is shown

Comment: Please check out my answer, that makes the page load once more, so screen reader would again see the alert for a second time and read its  message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to re-load your again. Add the script as below to your aspx page. Then, in your code-behind call the function `showAlert()` instead of your original start up script.

*Code-behind*

```
if (Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text.Trim()).DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
{
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "PopUp", "showAlert()", true);
  return;
}
```

*JavaScript*

```
<script>
function showAlert() {
alert('Previous week start date should be a Monday !');

if (getCookie("reloadPage") === "2" || getCookie("reloadPage") === "")
    {
        setCookie("reloadPage", "1",1);//create a persistent cookie
        window.location.reload(true);
    } else if(getCookie("reloadPage") === "1") {
        setCookie("reloadPage", "2",1);//create a persistent cookie
    }
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    try {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires + ";path=/";
    } catch (e) { }
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    try {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    } catch (e) { }
    return "";
}
</script>
```